# Set back ground color of tree view in wpf through code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, treeviewitem

The project I am working currently is in wpf and I am newer to wpf. In my project I want to search the tree view and when match occurs I need to highlight that element. I worked like this and I failed to set the back ground color of the node.

```
foreach (object item in treeView1.Items)
{
     cls.Node n=(cls.Node)item;
     n.IsSelected = true;               
}
```

Can anyone help me on this. the above code  is a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the wrapper `TreeViewItem` to set the Background. Because `TreeView` does not use VirtualizingStackPanel in its ItemsPanelTemplate, so we can safely use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to get a `TreeViewItem` from some item:

```
foreach (object item in treeView1.Items) {
  //cls.Node n=(cls.Node)item;
  //n.IsSelected = true;               
  var tvItem = treeView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) 
               as TreeViewItem;
  if(tvItem != null) tvItem.Background = Brushes.Blue;//just an example
}
```

I'm not sure if the original code (commented above) is your attempt or not, so just uncomment them if you want (`cls.Node` is actually your custom class).

Comment: @Sivajith I forgot mentioning that the code should be run when your window ***has already been loaded***. So try placing it in some `Loaded` event handler, or simply be sure that your window is still being shown before running the code.